# Unable to build app using dockers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, redis, docker-compose, sidekiq

I have setup of my application on DigitaOcean using dockers. It was working fine but few days back it stopped working. Whenever I want to build application and deploy it doesn't shows any progress.

By using following commands

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose stop && docker-compose up -d
```

systems stucks on the following output

```
db uses an image, skipping
elasticsearch uses an image, skipping
redis uses an image, skipping
Building app
```

It doesn't shows any furthur progress.
Following are the logs of `docker-compose`

```
db_1             | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1             | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1             | LOG:  shutting down
db_1             | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1             | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-01-10 
02:25:36 UTC
db_1             | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1             | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1             | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

redis_1          | 11264:C 26 Mar 15:20:17.028 # Failed opening the RDB 
file root (in server root dir /run) for saving: Permission denied
redis_1          | 1:M 26 Mar 15:20:17.127 # Background saving error
redis_1          | 1:M 26 Mar 15:20:23.038 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. 
Saving...
redis_1          | 1:M 26 Mar 15:20:23.038 * Background saving started by pid 11265

elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:25,729][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [_IRIbyW] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:28,794][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [_IRIbyW] new_master {_IRIbyW}{_IRIbyWCSoaUaKOLN93Fzg}{TFK38PIgRT6Kl62mTGBORg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:28,835][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [_IRIbyW] publish_address {172.17.0.4:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:28,838][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_IRIbyW] started
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:29,104][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [_IRIbyW] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-06T01:18:29,799][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [_IRIbyW] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[product_records][2]] ...]).
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-07T16:11:18,449][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_IRIbyW] stopping ...
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-07T16:11:18,575][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_IRIbyW] stopped
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-07T16:11:18,575][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_IRIbyW] closing ...
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-07T16:11:18,601][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_IRIbyW] closed
elasticsearch    | [2018-03-07T16:11:37,993][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...

WARNING: Connection pool is full, discarding connection: 'Ipaddress'
```

I am using `postgres` , `redis`, `elasticsearch` and `sidekiq` images in my rails application

But i have no clue where the things are going wrong.

Comment: can you post your docker compose file?